# What does 'a hair above the cycle low' mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

But credit card delinquencies cover just one kind of consumer debt. The New York Fed's report also showed that in the fourth quarter, total delinquencies were roughly stable. Balances that were 30 days late made up 1.1% of all balances in the fourth quarter, **a hair above the cycle low** of 1% recorded in Q1.

source: http://markets.businessinsider.com/news/stocks/bear-case-for-us-economy-slowdown-recession-torsten-slok-2017-2-1001761729-1001761729

Comment: Are you confused about 'the hair'? Because it basically refer to hair as being totally thin so that there is no feelable difference. The second part prolly refers to the stock cycle (4 stations where high and low are important)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The cycle low* is the low point in the cycle: 1.0%, recorded in Q1.

*A hair above the cycle low* is a quantity just a tiny bit higher than the cycle low—higher by the figurative width of a hair.